# jQuery elements not loading after ajax dynamic loaded webpage(s)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-plugins

jQuery elements like [Ibuttons](http://www.givainc.com/labs/ibutton_jquery_plugin.htm) does not work when its dynamically loaded via an ajax dynamic content loader

My entire site is entirely Rendered via Ajax
Like this

```
<html>
<header>
{jQuery}
</header>
<form method="post" action="" id="ajaxLoader" name="ajaxLoader" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <div id="Webpage"><!-- Ajax loader output --></div> </form>
</html>
```

Now after the Ajax loader is loaded by the browser it loads the content and outputs it in #Webpage, like so

```
[..]
<form method="post" action="" id="ajaxLoader" name="ajaxLoader" enctype="multipart/form-data">
              <div id="Webpage">{Content with jQuery plugins like ibuttons}</div> </form>
[...]
```

Now my Content(with jQuery elements)  works perfectly ok when its loaded with/out the ajax 
loader but when its loaded with the ajax loader the jquery plugins fail to work. please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to reinitialise the plugin with

`$("#my_button_id").iButton();`

after the ajax has finished loading if you haven't already done so.

**Edit**: Just a quick tip: it is good practice to have your javascript at the end on your `<body>` instead of on your page's `<head></head>`.

Comment: it works ok, but theres some plugins that cant be reinitialised like this.

Answer (score 1):

When you load webpages dynamically your jquery scripts in that page wont get register,use `jQuery.getScript()` to register them.

Documentation at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/